# JAVA client server reading string with new lines

Tags: java, client-server, bufferedreader, printwriter

I am writing a small program with a Client and a Server. The server program contains the calculator program in it. While the server and the client runs, the client can input and equation eg. 2 + 2 and the server will calculate it and send the answer to the client. The program should contain a help option as well so when the command help is sent from the client to the server, the server should return a help menu. 
My problem is that it is returning the help menu but all in one line, it is not printing it out to the console in separate lines. Thanks for any help.

SERVER CODE:

```
package One;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;


    public class ServerCalculator {

        static double answer;

        public ServerCalculator(){

            System.out.println("Server...");

            theServer();

            }
        void theServer(){

            try{

                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9990);
                while(true){

                    Socket sc = ss.accept();
                    Help hp = new Help();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
                    String compute = br.readLine();

                    Maths(compute);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream());

                    if(compute.equals("help")){
    //                  pw.println(hp.noOfLines());
                        pw.println(hp.menu());
                    }

                    if(compute.equals("exit")){
                        ss.close();
                    }

                    else{
                        pw.println(answer); 
                    }

                    pw.flush();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ee){
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        static double Maths(String compute){

          String message[] = compute.split(" ");


          if(message[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Help"))
          {
              return -2;
          }

          if(message[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
          {
              return -1;
          }


          double rad = 0;

          double a = Integer.parseInt(message[0]);
          double b = Integer.parseInt(message[2]);

          if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Sin")){
                rad = Math.toRadians(a);
                answer = Math.sin(rad);
            }
            if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Cos")){
                if(a==90 || a==270){
                    answer = 0;
                }
                else{
                    rad = Math.toRadians(a);
                    answer = Math.cos(rad);
                }
            }
            if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Tan")){
                if(a==90 || a==270){
                    System.out.println("Invalid Calculation");
                    answer =  0;
                }
                else if(a==45 || a==135){
                    rad = Math.toRadians(a);
                    answer = Math.tan(rad);
                }
                rad = Math.toRadians(a);
                answer = Math.tan(rad);
            }
        if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Power") || (message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("^")))
        {
            answer = Math.pow(a, b);  
        }

          if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Multiply") || (message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")))
          {
              answer = a*b;  
          }
          if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Add") || (message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("+")))
          {
            answer = a+b;
          }
          if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Subtract") || (message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-")))
          {
            answer = a-b;
          }
          if(message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Divide") || (message[1].equalsIgnoreCase("/")))
          {
            answer = a/b;
          }
            return answer;

      }


    }
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
package One;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

    public class ClientCalculator {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Socket sc;  

            System.out.println("Client...");

            while(true){

                try
                {
                    Scanner sin = new  Scanner(System.in);
                    String question = sin.nextLine(); 
                    System.out.println("Processing: " + question);


                    sc = new Socket("localhost",9990);

                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream());

                    pw.println(question);   
                    pw.flush();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
                    String answer = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(question + " = " + answer);
//                  sc.close();
//                  sin.close();
                }

                catch(Exception ee){

                }
            }
     }



    }
```

HELP MENU:

```
package One;

public class Help {

String menu(){

    String helpMenu = 
    "Instructions for the calculator " +
    "Input the number followed by space and then by word or operator and by number to get result " +
    "e.g. 5 + 5. or 30 Sin 30 - where 30 is the angle. " + 
    "Options are " + 
    "Multiply or (*) " + 
    "Add or (+) " +  
    "Subtract or (-) " + 
    "Divide or (/) " + 
    "Sin, Cos, Tan ";

    return helpMenu;

}


//  String noOfLines() {
//      
//      return "9";
//  }

}
```

RUN CODE:

```
package One;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerCalculator();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a while loop around your readline method in the client:

```
String answer = null;
while((answer=br.readLine()) != null)
{
//print answer
}
```

it is also preferred to use constants instead of hardcoding it: `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: this works fine for printing the menu on the console but it will only work once and afterward I am not able to sen any other commands to the server.

Comment: You are not closing the socket at your server.

Comment: If I close the socket ss I will than shut down the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use "\n" character for inserting a new line.

Replace

```
String helpMenu = 
    "Instructions for the calculator " +
    "Input the number followed by space and then by word or operator and by number to get result " +
    "e.g. 5 + 5. or 30 Sin 30 - where 30 is the angle. " + 
    "Options are " + 
    "Multiply or (*) " + 
    "Add or (+) " +  
    "Subtract or (-) " + 
    "Divide or (/) " + 
    "Sin, Cos, Tan ";
```

with

```
String helpMenu = 
    "Instructions for the calculator\n" +
    "Input the number followed by space and then by word or operator and by number to get result\n" +
    "e.g. 5 + 5. or 30 Sin 30 - where 30 is the angle. \n" + 
    "Options are \n" + 
    "Multiply or (*) \n" + 
    "Add or (+)\n " +  
    "Subtract or (-) \n" + 
    "Divide or (/) \n" + 
    "Sin, Cos, Tan \n";
```

Comment: Tried, does not work prints out only the first line and nothing than afterwards.

Comment: It is because in your Client code, you are calling `br.readLine();` only once.This just reads the first line. You should call it multiple times to read the subsequent lines. May be in some loop.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you are sending them in one line. You need to append a `newline (\n)` after each line, to display them in different lines.

Also Note: - Its better to use `StringBuilder`, if you want to use too much String Concatenation.

You can change your menu method to:

```
String menu(){
    StringBuilder helpMenu = new StringBuilder();

    helpMenu.append("Instructions for the calculator \n")
            .append("Input the number followed by space and then by word or operator and by number to get result \n")
            .append("e.g. 5 + 5. or 30 Sin 30 - where 30 is the angle. \n")
            .append("Options are: \n")
            .append("\tMultiply or (*) \n")
            .append("\tAdd or (+) \n")
            .append("\tSubtract or (-) \n")
            .append("\tDivide or (/) \n")
            .append("\tSin, Cos, Tan \n");

    return helpMenu.toString();

}
```

Comment: I have tried to use the StringBuilder but the problem is it will only print out the first line and that's all.

Comment: @Saint.. Did you add a `newline` at the end of each line?

Comment: this works fine for printing the menu on the console but it will only work once and afterward I am not able to send any other commands to the server.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt.. What? Do you mean, the duplicate answers on every question are cheated upon? Improve your thinking. I was going through the code, when OP said, the previous change was not working. See previous comments. In the meantime, I think Captain posted his answer. At least don't blame for stealing such answers. Even then, I'll remove the edit for you.